# How to split vector according to indices given in another vector?

Tags: c++, vector, split

I have a source `std::vector<double>`, which I'd like to split according to indices contained in `std::vector<int>`. The split is inclusive, and start of next slice should start where previous left off, starting from start of the source vector.

For example:

```
{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 } -> source
{2, 4, 7 } -> split indices
```

and after applying the function it should produce:

```
{1.1, 2.2, 3.3}
{4.4, 5.5} 
{6.6, 7.7, 8.8}
```

I have this which won't give me the third vector and so on:

```
vector<double> nets{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7 };

vector<vector<double>> periodnumbers;
vector<double> numbers;

for (int i = 0; i < nets.size(); i++)
{
    double temp;
    temp = nets[i];
    numbers.push_back(temp);
    for (int j = 0; j < ends.size(); j++)
    {
        if (i == ends[j])
        {
            periodnumbers.push_back(numbers);
            numbers.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have 4 sub-vectors, not 2?

Comment: I'm confused by exactly how `ends` works -- why should the example you give output what you want it to?

Comment: I have edited to make my question more clear - hopefully.

Comment: @Choy What about `9.9`? Do you just toss it out since `ends` only has 3 ends in it?

Comment: @Nathan yes I would like that if possible.

Comment: what do you intend to do with these `vector`s afterwards? Wouldn't it be simplier to use some kind of `span`s or copy-on-write structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bad algorithm

Even if it worked, it is doing too many unnecessary operations. Starting from looping over all elements, ending with `push_back`ing, instead of reserving/resizing.

### Better algorithm

Lets assume `ends` is sorted. Then one can just take two "sliders", and keep moving them. The left slider starts on start of the source vector, and the right one starts on the first end. As algorithm progresses, it copies current range inside sliders, moves left slider to right slider, and right slider becomes next end.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::vector<double>> split_ends(const std::vector<double>& source, const std::vector<int>& ends) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;
    result.reserve(ends.size());
    auto anchor_front = source.begin();
    for (auto one_end: ends) {
        auto anchor_end = std::next(source.begin(), one_end + 1);
        result.emplace_back(anchor_front, anchor_end);
        anchor_front = anchor_end;
    }

    return result;
}

#include <iostream>

void print(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
    for (auto x: v) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> nets{1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9};
    std::vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7};

    auto splitted = split_ends(nets, ends);
    for (const auto& v: splitted) {
        print(v);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OMZsPSIHOj3vK5tj).

Output:

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 
4.4 5.5 
6.6 7.7 8.8
```

---

The algorithm above assumes `ends` is sorted and doesn't contain out of range indices. If a copy is not needed, one might just save the endpoints iterators, and perform changes on the source directly.

Comment: Honestly, `emplace` is overrated. Most types have a trivial move-constructor.

Comment: @o11c, I was lazy to type the name or use `{}`. Writing inside of wandbox's editor is not exactly pleasant, but a nice exercise to keep myself fit.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm still a beginner, I guess, in C++.  I wasn't even aware of methods like next or emplace_back or even reserve. I will definitely add them to my artillery.

Comment: @Choy, I recommend reviewing the edit I proposed. If you're new to the language, I recommend grabbing a good book and reading it. There was a curated list on SO

Comment: @o11c, `std::array` is a black sheep in that story :) but I guess it has feats that completely dwarf the inconvenience.

Comment: @Incomputable I've gone through Programming: Principles  and  Practice  Using  C++ in an class - if that helps place me on the spectrum of C++ experience.

Comment: @Choy, unfortunately I didn't read that book ... I'm raised by the community here and on CodeReview, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in `if(i == ends[i])`

One option is to use another variable.

```
vector<double> nets{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7};

vector<vector<double>> periodnumbers;
vector<double> numbers;
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i < nets.size(); i++)
{
    double temp;
    temp = nets[i];
    numbers.push_back(temp);
    //cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;

    if (i == ends[j])
    {
        //cout<<i<<"  "<<nets[i]<<endl;
        periodnumbers.push_back(numbers);
        numbers.clear();
        j++;
        //break;
    }
    //cout<<numbers[i]<<endl;

    }
    cout<<"Size"<<periodnumbers.size()<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<periodnumbers.size();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<periodnumbers[i].size();j++){
            cout<<periodnumbers[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of details that I'm not sure you've considered. My answer is tweakable.

In particular, I would prefer `WEIRD_OFFSET` to be 0.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;


const bool ONLY = true;
const bool BEFORE_FIRST = true;
const bool AFTER_LAST = true;

const bool ALLOW_EMPTY = true;
const size_t WEIRD_OFFSET = 1;

template<class T>
vector<vector<T>> frob(const vector<T>& nets, const vector<int>& ends)
{
    vector<vector<T>> rv;
    if (ends.empty())
    {
        if (ONLY)
        {
            if (ALLOW_EMPTY || !nets.empty())
                rv.push_back(nets);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (BEFORE_FIRST)
        {
            auto bi = 0;
            auto ei = ends[0] + WEIRD_OFFSET;

            assert (0 <= bi && bi <= ei && ei <= nets.size());
            auto b = nets.begin() + bi;
            auto e = nets.begin() + ei;
            if (ALLOW_EMPTY || b != e)
                rv.push_back(vector<T>(b, e));
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < ends.size() - 1; ++i)
        {
            auto bi = ends[i] + WEIRD_OFFSET;
            auto ei = ends[i+1] + WEIRD_OFFSET;

            assert (0 <= bi && bi <= ei && ei <= nets.size());
            auto b = nets.begin() + bi;
            auto e = nets.begin() + ei;
            if (ALLOW_EMPTY || b != e)
                rv.push_back(vector<T>(b, e));
        }
        if (AFTER_LAST)
        {
            auto bi = ends.back() + WEIRD_OFFSET;
            auto ei = nets.size();

            assert (0 <= bi && bi <= ei && ei <= nets.size());
            auto b = nets.begin() + bi;
            auto e = nets.begin() + ei;
            if (ALLOW_EMPTY || b != e)
                rv.push_back(vector<T>(b, e));
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> nets{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
    vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7};

    vector<vector<double>> periodnumbers = frob(nets, ends);
    for (const auto& v : periodnumbers)
    {
        for (const auto& i : v)
        {
            cout << i << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << std::flush;
}
```

This produces:

```
1.1 2.2 3.3 
4.4 5.5 
6.6 7.7 8.8 
9.9
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that `ends` is sorted in ascending order and the values in `ends` are never larger than the size of `nets` allows them to be, then there is a rather simple function that can give you the desired result:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> split(const std::vector<T>& nets, const std::vector<int>& ends)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
    int previous_offset = 0;
    for (int i : ends)
    {
        const std::vector<T> piece(nets.begin() + previous_offset, nets.begin() + i + 1);
        previous_offset = i;
        result.push_back(piece);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The whole program with your example data could look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// function from above
template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> split(const std::vector<T>& nets, const std::vector<int>& ends)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result;
    int previous_offset = 0;
    for (int i : ends)
    {
        const std::vector<T> piece(nets.begin() + previous_offset, nets.begin() + i + 1);
        previous_offset = i;
        result.push_back(piece);
    }
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    // input data
    std::vector<double> nets{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
    std::vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7 };
    // variable that will hold the result
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> periodnumbers;

    // This is where the work happens.
    periodnumbers = split(nets, ends);

    // Write result to standard output.
    std::cout << "There are " << static_cast<int>(periodnumbers.size()) << " pieces:" << std::endl;
    for (auto vec : periodnumbers)
    {
        std::cout << "Next piece is: ";
        for (auto elem: vec)
        {
            std::cout << elem << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
There are 3 pieces:
Next piece is: 1.1 2.2 3.3 
Next piece is: 3.3 4.4 5.5 
Next piece is: 5.5 6.6 7.7 8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following code which is much simpler and easier to understand

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<double> nets{ 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9 };
  vector<int> ends{2, 4, 7 };
  ends.push_back(nets.size()-1);
  vector<vector<double>> periodnumbers;
  vector<double> numbers;
  int j=0;
  int coming_split_index=ends[j];
  for (int i = 0; i < nets.size(); i++){
     if(i<=coming_split_index){
       numbers.push_back(nets[i]);
     }else{
         j++;
         coming_split_index=ends[j];
         periodnumbers.push_back(numbers);
         numbers.clear();
         i--;

        /*when the index i reaches the coming index the corresponding 
        *value won't be added to any subvector because It will skip the 
        *pervious instruction for this reason I decrement the counter i so 
        *that it repeats it and the next time the one in the previous will 
        *be executed
        */

        }
   }
```

this displays your results

```
 1.1 2.2 3.3 
 4.4 5.5 
 6.6 7.7 8.8
```